# Which JDK version can I use to support Lombok version 1.16.16?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-8, pom.xml, lombok

I have the following dependency in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <optional>true</optional>
    <version>1.16.16</version>
</dependency>
```

When I run `mvn clean install` I get the following error:

```
Fatal error compiling: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: com.sun.tools.javac.code.TypeTags -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

I found many articles which suggest that I should either upgrade the Lombok version or I should use **JDK 8**. I am running JDK 8 but still not able to fix this error. Can someone tell me the exact **JDK version** that I should use in order to get rid of this error?

Comment: Waht does it say about it in the Lombok 1.16.16 release notes?

Comment: Which JDK are you using for the logs you've shared? What is it that stopped you from fixing it on JDK8?

Comment: @Naman I am running jdk 1.8.0_131 but still getting the error.

Comment: Did you installed the lombok jar ?

Comment: Pretty sure Lombok supports JDK 6+, so there is no reason for you to change version.

Answer (score 0):

Dependency will help you getting that jar. Since Lombok works while code compilation you need to install the Lombok jar

[Refer to this link for installation of Lombok in your IDE](https://www.baeldung.com/lombok-ide#eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

If you use Intellij, you need install plugin Lombok